# Bulk deleting all emails within "inbox" folder from a specific mailbox using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, directory, exchange-server, bulk

I'm trying to delete 48000 emails within the "Inbox" folder of a  specific mailbox called "GTV Info". I only want to delete all the emails within the "Inbox" folder and keep the "Inbox" folder empty.

Exchange Server 2007 SP1    08.01.0436.000

I'm issuing this command, and this is the error message that I'm getting:

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Export-Mailbox -Identity "GTV Info"
-IncludeFolders "\Inbox" -StartDate "16/11/2009" -EndDate "24/08/2011" -DeleteContent

Confirm Are you sure you want to perform this action? Searching the contents and/or the associated messages from the mailbox 'GTV Info' and deleting those messages that meet the criteria specified. This operation may take a long time to complete. [Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):A Export-Mailbox : Error was found for GTV Info (info@gt-vehicles.com) because: E rror occurred in the step: Moving messages. Failed to copy messages to the dest ination mailbox store with error: MAPI or an unspecified service provider. ID no: 00000000-0000-00000000, error code: -1056749164 At line:1 char:15
+ Export-Mailbox <<<<  -Identity "GTV Info" -IncludeFolders "\Inbox" -StartDate  "16/11/2009" -EndDate "24/08/2011" -DeleteContent
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [Export-Mailbox], Re    cipientTaskException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 35CD2975,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Recipient    Tasks.ExportMailbox



Identity                         : gtv.local/MyBusiness/Users/SBSUsers/GTV Info DistinguishedName         : CN=GTV Info,OU=SBSUsers,OU=Users,OU=MyBusine
                                   ss,DC=gtv,DC=local DisplayName                      : GTV Info Alias                            : info LegacyExchangeDN    : /o=First Organization/ou=Exchange Administra
                                   tive Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/c
                                   n=info PrimarySmtpAddress               : info@gt-vehicles.com SourceServer                     : SAGITARIUS.gtv.local SourceDatabase                   : SAGITARIUS\First Storage Group\Mailbox Datab
                                   ase SourceGlobalCatalog              : SAGITARIUS SourceDomainController           : TargetGlobalCatalog    : SAGITARIUS TargetDomainController           : TargetMailbox          : TargetServer                     : TargetDatabase                   : MailboxSize                      : 1928KB IsResourceMailbox          : False SIDUsedInMatch                   : SMTPProxies                 : SourceManager                    : SourceDirectReports              : SourcePublicDelegates            : SourcePublicDelegatesBL          : SourceAltRecipient               : SourceAltRecipientBL             : SourceDeliverAndRedirect         : MatchedTargetNTAccountDN         : IsMatchedNTAccountMailboxEnabled : MatchedContactsDNList            : TargetNTAccountDNToCreate        : TargetManager                    : TargetDirectReports              : TargetPublicDelegates            : TargetPublicDelegatesBL          : TargetAltRecipient               : TargetAltRecipientBL             : TargetDeliverAndRedirect         : Options                          : DeleteSourceContent SourceForestCredential           : TargetForestCredential           : TargetFolder                     : PSTFilePath                      : RsgMailboxGuid                   : RsgMailboxLegacyExchangeDN       : RsgMailboxDisplayName            : RsgDatabaseGuid                  : StandardMessagesDeleted          : 0 AssociatedMessagesDeleted        : 0 DumpsterMessagesDeleted          : 0 MoveType                      : DeleteOnly MoveStage                        : Move StartTime         : 26/08/2015 13:12:15 EndTime                          : 26/08/2015 13:12:16 StatusCode                       : -1056749164 StatusMessage  : Error occurred in the step: Moving messages.
                                    Failed to copy messages to the destination
                                   mailbox store with error:
                                   MAPI or an unspecified service provider.
                                   ID no: 00000000-0000-00000000 ReportFile                       : C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\L
                                   ogging\MigrationLogs\export-Mailbox20150826-
                                   131211-5306000.xml



[PS] C:\Windows\system32>
```

I'm very stuck with this, I really need help from this awesome community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your command you are missing a destination to export the e-mails to.

Your not working command:

```
Export-Mailbox -Identity "GTV Info" -IncludeFolders "\Inbox" -StartDate "16/11/2009" -EndDate "24/08/2011" -DeleteContent
```

With a destination defined it looks like this:

```
Export-Mailbox -Identity "GTV Info" -IncludeFolders "\Inbox" -StartDate "16/11/2009" -EndDate "24/08/2011" -DeleteContent -PSTFolderPath 'C:\PSTFiles\Mails.pst'
```

See [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc535123.aspx) for examples and [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa998579(v=EXCHG.80).aspx) for more info on the available parameters.

Comment: I have just issued the command as you suggest and now I get this error message:

Export-Mailbox -Identity "GTV Info" -IncludeFolders "\Inbox" -StartDate "16/11/2009" -EndDate "24/08/2011" -DeleteContent -PSTFolderPat
h 'C:\Temp\Mails.pst'
You are running on a 64-bit computer. To export to or import from a .pst file,
you must be running a 32-bit computer that has Outlook 2003 SP2 or later installed.

Comment: First hit on Google, see [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/c556dff2-9b90-4fc6-b691-fb3ce8be6602/export-mailboxes-from-exchange-2007-to-pst-unable-to-from-exchange-mgt-shell?forum=exchangesvrgenerallegacy) for your answer.